# Mysql Trigger Insert row Another Table using matching data

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `UrunPaketDetay`(
    `UrunPaketDetay` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `UrunPaketNo` int NULL, 
    `Tarih` date NULL, 
    `Barkod` varchar(14) NOT NULL, 
    `Urun` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `SunumSekli` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `IslemeSekli` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `PaketlemeSekli` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kalibre` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kilo` double NULL, 
    `GlazeOran` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Uretici` varchar(190) NULL, 
    `PaletKod` varchar(50) NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`UrunPaketDetay`)
)CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE `CkisEks`(
    `CikId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `Tarih` date NULL, 
    `Musteri` varchar(190) NULL, 
    `TeslimatYer` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `CikisSaati` time NULL, 
    `AracPlakasi` varchar(18) NULL, 
    `AracTel` varchar(16) NULL, 
    `KonteynirNo` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `PaletKod` varchar(12) NULL, 
    `Kilo` double NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`CikId`)
)CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Ckis_Detay`(
    `CD_Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `CikId` int NULL, 
    `Barkod` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Urun` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kalibre` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Kilo` double NULL, 
    `Uretici` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Musteri` varchar(190) NULL, 
    `PaletKod` varchar(50) NULL, 
    `Tarih` date NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`CD_Id`)
)CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I fill up my first table. After on 2nd table I call PaletKod row. PaletKod row autofill Kilo Row on 2nd table from 1st table.

But I need when I fill PaletKod to my 2nd table how can I select Paletkod from first table and fill my 3rd table values (Uretici, Urun, Kilo, Kalibre )?

I need trigger code. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

From My Understanding to do this,

```
 DELIMITER $$
  CREATE TRIGGER Insert_UrunPaketDetay 
  AFTER INSERT ON UrunPaketDetay
  FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO Ckis_Detay (Uretici,Urun,Kilo,Kalibre)
  VALUES 
  (UrunPaketDetay.Uretici,UrunPaketDetay.Urun
   ,UrunPaketDetay.Kilo,UrunPaketDetay.Kalibre);
 END$$  
 DELIMITER ;
```

> Try this code